# How to setup properly RichTextBox tool or coding to account delimited and tab space on string (i.e. proper format of text)

Tags: vb.net, format, text-files, richtextbox, notepad

I am using the following coding to send text (string variable) to a text file (notepad.exe) and to a RichTextBox on a Dialog form.

```
Private Sub OutputToScreen(ByRef AnyString As String)

    Dialog1.RichTextBox.Text &= AnyString + vbCrLf

End Sub
```

However, I have the following issue. After subroutine is completed, the text file (notepad.exe ) is formatted successfully. But the output on RichTextBox is not formatted successfully (Please see screenshots below).

Any suggestions to define / setup this properly for RichTextBox?

[Notepad Screenshot - Result: Output is OK!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KICSH.png)

[RichTextBox on Dialog Form Screenshot - Result: Output is NOT OK.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yW1VU.png)

Comment: RTF defaults to inches (or points - there are 1440 to the inch). 0.5 in (720 pt or 12.7 mm) is the default. Edit boxes default to *Dialog Units* which the default is 8 times the dialog character unit width, which is based on the dialog font. RTF is based on paper while edit boxes are based on screen dialogs. Change the default tabstop on RTF to 0.75 in.

Comment: Not an answer, is there a reason why you’re not showing tabular data in control such as a data grid view that was specifically designed for it?

Comment: Change the RTB's font to a [monospaced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_monospaced_typefaces) one. And why the `AnyString` param is passed by reference? You don't need `ByRef` in this context.

Comment: Thank for all your answers. The solution was selecting a monospaced font. Font "Courier New" is a monospaced font and worked very well.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a variable-width font in your RTB while Notepad is using a fixed-width font. Change the font and it will look the same.

Comment: The font was changed to "Courier New" and worked very well. Thank you.